# raw json to html table format

Tags: json, html-table

I want to display raw json in tabular format, I have seen jquery plugins but that need heading/labels to display, In my case, its not predefined ( means anything possible in json).

How can I display that in HTML table format ?

Answer (score 1):

I found this engine on [Hacker News](http://news.ycombinator.com/) today, it might be what you're looking for.

[Tempo - a tiny JSON rendering engine](http://twigkit.github.com/tempo/)

Comment: **In my case, its not predefined.** Can't define template :(

Comment: You don't know how the JSON will be structured? Do they structure it by random? They include no template? The API or whatever that's returning the JSON must be very poorly designed... Could you give two sample JSON maybe?

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this simple project on Github : [Json-To-HTML-Table](https://github.com/afshinm/Json-to-HTML-Table)

Answer (score 0):

> jQuery JSON-to-table plugin (demonstration) is a jQuery plugin that
>   can represent hierarchical data (JSON) in HTML table.
>
> The script is developed to handle all data types passable through
>   JSON. At any time only one level of data is shown. The data tree can
>   be navigated from node-to-node without refreshing the page.

https://github.com/anuary/jquery-json-to-table

This script exactly that – it allows you to display raw JSON data in HTML table without any pre-defined templates.